# How to pass array's size as another argument with sizeof

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the function below :

```
addToTxBuffer((uint8_t []){0x01,0x11}, 2, zeroPad);
```

The second argument `2` is the `size` of first argument. I would like to use `sizeof` instead of `2`. Is there any syntax that makes it possible? i.e. :

```
addToTxBuffer((uint8_t header[]){0x01,0x11}, sizeof(header), zeroPad);
```

this does not work though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compound literals are unnamed, so you can't reference them in that way.  You would need to define the array separately, then you can get its size:

```
uint8_t header[] = {0x01,0x11};
addToTxBuffer(header, sizeof(header), zeroPad);
```

Comment: A macro could serve to provide both a pointer to and the size of a compound literal.